# How to remove the warning "this might be empty" from result view in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am showing few information to the user on card and structure has `min(Optional)` and I don't want to change that. There is possibility that it might be blank. But how to put it in condition in `result-view`. I tried like `if(this.name)` but then yellow line appears on condition and template both.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `if` statement is the correct way.

For example, here is how a capsule I have written will handle an optional `gameTitle` property when displaying my `Character` structure.

```
if(exists(character.gameTitle)) {
  cell-card {
    slot2 {
      content {
        order (PrimarySecondary)
          primary ("#{value(character.gameTitle)}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```